# Grid View lags when scrolling

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview, android-gridview

I have a grid view with 32 elements or images. The images are quite low quality and are not more than 300kb. Everytime I scroll, the grid view lags, and it lags quite noticeably. I would like to get ideas or actual code about what next to do.

I've tried making pictures even lower quality but it did not help. Only if I use one image for all 32 elements in grid view everything forks fine, but as soon as I have more difrent images it lags.

my class:

```
private GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<CreateProduct> products;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_products_grid_view);

        products = new ArrayList<CreateProduct>();
        createAllProducts2();

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.allProductGrid);
        GridAdapter customAdapter = new GridAdapter(this, products);
        gridView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                CreateProduct x = products.get(i);
                goToProductDetails(x.productName, x.id, x.productDesc,x.productKulise, x.image);
            }
        });

    }
```

my adapter:

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<CreateProduct> arrayGrid;
    Context context;

    public GridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CreateProduct> arrayList){
        this.arrayGrid = arrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayGrid.size();
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final CreateProduct product = arrayGrid.get(i);
        if (view == null){
            final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_row, null);
        }
        final TextView title33 = view.findViewById(R.id.titleGrid);
        final ImageView image33 = view.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

        title33.setText(product.productName);
        image33.setImageResource(product.image);

        return view;
    }
}
```

ma grid_row xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="130sp"
        android:layout_height="130sp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/comment_button_product_details"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleGrid"
        android:layout_width="130sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/product_name"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I dont get any error messages. I would like the grid view to not lag.

Comment: comment  image33.setImageResource(product.image); this line and verify still lagging or not

Comment: either try using Glide or migrate to RecyclerView

Comment: if I comment that line everything works perfectly. It also works fine up to 8 images but then it starts to lag.
Thank you I will google glide and try it to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve lagging, you should use ViewHolder pattern in your **gridView adapter**. I tried to google a bit and I found this sample, which can help you: https://github.com/first087/Android-ViewHolder-Example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/artitk/android_viewholder_example/GridViewActivity.java

Especially check how to make `ViewHolder` and `setTag` to view container, so adapter can recycle items properly without any performance appliances.

For next step I suggest that you get rid of `GridView` and use instead `RecyclerView`, because it's much more powerful and performant.

For loading images use Glide or any other similar libraries for loading images efficiently.

Comment: Ok thank you a lot ! I will use Recycler View and try Glide for loading images , hope that works. Also if you know any article or good explanation about ViewHolder and setTag please let me know because I've never heard or done anything with it.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-your-listview , Here you can read a bit more.. It's an old tutorial, but explanation is still valid and pretty good.

Comment: I just used glide and now everything works perfectly. But I still want to do it more "properly" so thanks for link(s) and explanation :)